# Is ambiguous cfg(context free grammar) more expressive than unambiguous cfg?

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-languages, ambiguous-grammar

I found that the following ambiguous cfg can not expressed by unambiguous cfg:

```
S → a S B | x
B → a | ε
```

such as:
aaxa:
S → a S B → a a S B B → a a x B B → a a x ε B or a a x B ε

I tried to ask for chat gpt ,but it gives me wrong answer.
And I can not convert it to unambiguous grammar by known method